# Use custom regular expressions to validate form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, custom-data-attribute

I would like to validate the form using my custom data attributes but not sure how this is done. I also want to display the error messages in the data attributes if required.

I am looking for the JavaScript which matches the regex values from the data attributes and matches it against the corresponding input values.

I have the following form..

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="Username">Username:</label>
                            <input type="email" data-validation-error="Please enter a username" data-validation-use="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" id="username" name="username" maxlength="254" class="required" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="Password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" data-validation-error="Please enter a password" data-validation-use="^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,12}$" id="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="12" class="required" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing for modern browsers only, you can use a few nice features for this:

1. List itemUse input type *email* for the username field. The browser will take care of the validation.
2. Use attribute *required*. The browser won't let the user submit without a value in the field.
3. Use attribute *pattern*. The browser won't let the user submit without the value matching the given pattern. Altough, with email type, you could skip the horrible regex matching emails of yours :)

Check out the pattern attribute:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/#section_6

Example:

```
<input type="email" required />
```

Here you can check out the support for modern form features in the most used browsers:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms

There is an ongoing discussion if it should be possible to specify and style the error messages (handled by the browser). As for now, I don't think it's possible to style the validation messages. Maybe it's more user friendly if these messages is equal across all pages?

If you need to support older browsers, you'll have to put javascript event handlers on each field, extract the regex from the data attributes and match it against the value. Keep in mind that client side validation is no substitute for server side validation - it's just for user convenience. Therefore, HTML5 validation could be good enough for those with browsers supporting it - the rest will still have server side validation to rely on, altought the user experience won't be that great.

This example shows how it could be done (I haven't tested this very well :o):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var isValid = true;
    $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
        var regex = new RegExp($(this).attr('data-validation-use'));
        if(!regex.exec($(this).val())){
            $('.validationError').append($(this).attr('data-validation-error'));
            $(this).addClass('invalid');
            isValid = false;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
});
```

Comment: I will need to support older browsers so i may not include HTML5 only validation. I need to use the data attribute, as shown in my code for this particular example so was ideally looking for a regex answer.

Comment: Also, I have managed to extract the regex from the data attributes, but i am unsure how to match it against the input fields. That bit of Javascript is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

jquery validation will be best. 
See the demo and code of standard jQuery validation here. [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)